# How to Confirm that Child Activity has been finished before starting that child again?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a parent activity A which has two childs activities B and C. When I open Parent Activity A it decides which child activity have to open. (function using `startActivityForResult`) eg. A decide to open B. B plays Video and return result to back. thats fine next if A decide to open B again. B is not opening fine (not playing video).

**Note:**
Following is Fine:

A-->B and A<--B

then

A-->C and A<--C

then

A-->B and A<--B

But Following is Not Working:

A-->B and A<--B

then

A-->B and A<--B  //When try to move again on B. I think A is calling B again before it finished

then

A-->C and A<--C

Any Idea to solve this problem??

Mean how can i get that child activity has beed finished before calling that child again??

Following is the code of Parent Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"requestCode: "+requestCode+" : resultCode : "+ resultCode);
        finishActivity(requestCode);
        playProgram(requestCode);
    }

    private void playProgram(int requestCode){
        if(requestCode == QUESTION_WRAPPER){
            currentChap = currentChap + 1;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MovieWrapperActivity.this, VideoWrapperActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("chaptertoplay", currentChap);
            intent.putExtra("videofile",  Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(currentChap).getVideoURL());
            startActivityForResult(intent, MOVIE_WRAPPER);
        }else if(requestCode == MOVIE_WRAPPER) {
            if(Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(currentChap).isQuiz()){
                Intent in2 = new Intent(MovieWrapperActivity.this, QuestionWrapper.class);
                in2.putExtra("chaptertoplay", currentChap);
                startActivityForResult(in2, QUESTION_WRAPPER);

            }else{
                currentChap = currentChap + 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MovieWrapperActivity.this, VideoWrapperActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("chaptertoplay", currentChap);
                intent.putExtra("videofile",  Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(currentChap).getVideoURL());
                startActivityForResult(intent, MOVIE_WRAPPER);
            }
        }
    }
```

Code of B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    init();
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
    mController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mController);
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Completed");
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            mVideoView = null;
            mController = null;
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

I think Media Elements in B are taking time to destroy or not even being destroyed.

Comment: "Calling it before it finished" is impossible. If you're returning to A, B is closed. Maybe (just maybe), B might be closing down when `onActivityResult` is called but anywhere else in A should be fine.

Post your code.

Comment: `B might be closing down when onActivityResult` Yes this is happening.

Comment: Don't try to restart `B` in `onActivityResult` (it's a bit outside of the lifecycle events). Set a flag and restart `B` from, say, `A.onStart()`

Comment: I already have tried `A.onStart()` thing was also not working. I have to manage the solution by following working thing. A-->B and A<--B

then

A-->C and A<--C

then

A-->B and A<--B

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent output = new Intent();
    output.putExtra("DATA", data);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK  , output);
    finish();
```

Just call `finish()` after setting result.

Answer (score 0):

U have to call finish() after setresult() in child activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"requestCode: "+requestCode+" : resultCode : "+ resultCode);
        finishActivity(requestCode);//dont finish child activity here.
        playProgram(requestCode);
    }
```

Comment: don't call finishActivity(requestCode) inside parent activity as it already finish by calling finish() inside child activity.

Comment: `dont call finishActivity(requestCode) inside parent activity` I have tried this as well. :(
I added `finishActivity(requestCode);` just for testing may be it will work.

Comment: @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Completed");
            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();#check out this line
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            mVideoView = null;
            mController = null;
            finish();
        }

Comment: call getIntent() inside onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) mtd and assign it to  Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);